# getting openCv error- Image step is wrong in EigenFaces.Predict() method

Tags: java, opencv, javacv, face-recognition

I am getting error in EigenFaces.predict() method in java cv face recognition. The error is-

> OpenCV Error: Image step is wrong (The matrix is not continuous, thus its number of rows can not be changed) in unknown function, file ......\src\opencv\modules\core\src\matrix.cpp, line 802

My code is-

```
public static void main(String[] args)  {
    long size=6;
    MatVector imgs=new MatVector(size);
    int[] id={0,0,0,0,0,0};

    FaceRecognizer fr=opencv_contrib.createEigenFaceRecognizer();
    for(int i=0;i<=5;i++)
    {
        String url="C:/Users/vivek/Documents/NetBeansProjects/Recognizer2/src/a"+(i+1)+".jpg";
        IplImage img=opencv_highgui.cvLoadImage(url);
        imgs=imgs.put(i,img);

    }
    fr.train(imgs,id);
    IplImage testImage=opencv_highgui.cvLoadImage("C:/Users/vivek/Documents/NetBeansProjects/Recognizer2/src/a3.jpg");
    CvMat mat= testImage.asCvMat();
    int val=fr.predict(mat);
    System.out.println(val);
```

}

Comment: All images are preprocessed, grey scaled and of same size(70*70). I am using open cv-2.4.7.

Comment: when I am using LBPfaceRecognizer, it gives error- OpenCV Error: The function/feature is not implemented (Using Original Local Binary Patterns for feature extraction only works on single-channel images (given 16) Please pass the image data as a grayscale image!).

Comment: My training and test images are gray scaled and pre processed but thier nChanel value is 3. I think this is causing the problem. Is it necessary that the images should have nChanel value 1?

Comment: Yeah I converted the images to nChannel value 1, it is working fine with LBPH FaceceRecognizer but getting same above mentioned error with Eigen FaceRecognizer and FisherFace Recognizer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally I got the solution of my problem. The size of my test and training images were 70*70.
I changed the size to 200*200 and now it is working perfectly. The reason behind it is that EigenFaceRecognizer and FisherFaceRecognizer don't work with image width that are not multiple of 8 or 16(In my case).
70 is not multiple of 8 so it is not working but for image width 200(multiple of 8), it is working fine.